# Internationalization in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html, unicode, internationalization

Which is the best practice to implement internationalization in AngularJS?
Should I use Unicode or Angular Translate service (i18n)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use i18n in my opinion. This prevents you from making multiple templates and other resources except translation files. Also you'll be able to use translate filter out-of-box like this:

```
{{ 'KEY_OBJECT.STRING'|translate }}
```

Any file you're editing is better to save in UTF-8 encoding.